# Disable Control+Alt+End

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, vnc

## Background

In xfce4, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> hotkey cycles to the next workspace. The settings for this can be displayed from the command line using:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv | grep -i end
```

This reveals:

```
/xfwm4/custom/<Alt><Control>End            move_window_next_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Alt><Control>End           move_window_next_workspace_key
/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>End           move_window_next_workspace_key
```

## Problem

When using VNC to connect to a Windows terminal, Windows authentication software prompts the user to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to authenticate.

## Question

How do you remove the hotkey for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> so that the hotkey passes through to VNC?

## Idea

The following did not work:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/xfwm4/default/<Alt><Control>End" --type string --set ''
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/xfwm4/custom/<Alt><Control>End" --type string --set ''
xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/xfwm4/default/<Primary><Alt>End" --type string --set ''
```

The hotkey continues to cycle the desktops.

Comment: As far as I remember, vnc translates Ctrl+Alt+End to Ctrl+Alt+Del on the viewed machine because it assumes that both server and viewer are windows machines.

Wouldn't it be better if vnc did not do this on a non-windows host?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing (or changin) the appropriate entry(s) in the `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks, Emil, but the values mapped for **Alt+Control+End** in that file are currently empty strings.

Comment: maybe a global config in `/etc`. try `find /etc -name xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a programmer. I use defaults.  Hard-coded defaults that can be overwritten by a variable.  Which I again set to my default as an example...

So, have you tried setting it to *something else* then a null string?  comes to mind... ;)